# How to reuse usercontrol between 2 web applications

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, .net-4.0

I will try to explain as best as I can what I realy want to do here. But must say that I'm french and it's a bit tricky to explain.

**Scenario**
We are developping many web applications for differents companies. We rapidly notice that between two sites, many things that we've made come often times so we're looking to encapsulate part of our frontend into UserControl so it will be reusable (spend less time in same case ; time is money!)

**The problem**
The problem we have is that we always have to copy everything (image, css, js etc) which a UserControl can have. Also, it's hard to remember at every modification;

- "*Ok, I've changed something in the usercontrol, so, I must go change it in every instance of this usercontrol into all sites that use it (and at the exact good line)*".

So, the best solution for us is to create a ASP.net Server Control library. At least we thought...

**Question**
So, we've try this and we quickly get at the bottom of the wall. How to we do that? I mean, there's no design mode. It's ok if you want to change the way a textbox act, or a button. But, how when you create something realy custom but reusable. Like, for exemple, a Date picker, with 5 dropdowns (Months, days year hours minutes)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you more sensitive to deployment/maintenance pain or design pain?  For ease of deployment and distribution, I'd say switch to a server control.  Then it becomes a standard assembly deployment question and you get a lot of relatively painless options.

If sacrificing the ease of GUI design is unacceptable then you're stuck either doing what you're describing and using some kind of mechanism to copy/paste markup across all the sites that use it, or seriously hacking resources or other inline repository to store the markup in an assembly and injecting markup into the control at runtime to achieve quasi-server control behavior.  I wouldn't recommend going the latter route unless you really, REALLY need to.

Comment: Well, it seems to be difficult for something that seems, at first view, to be good to have! Do you know any exemple of how to do that (about the first point ; I can live without design if it's a realy pain)? Thanks in advance

Comment: There are a ton of good server control tutorials out there that can help you get started far more effectively than I can.  ;o)

Comment: Thank you, found one ... easly :oP

Answer (score 2):

In short and beyond copy+paste, you can't reuse User Controls across applications. If you want to reuse controls, you need to use a server control which is compiled into a library.

Comment: But server control have no "Design" mode, so we can't put as many controls as we want? Like my date picker exemple? No?

Comment: You can put anything you want into a server control.  You just have to do it programmatically.  It's not that bad for something fairly compact like a date picker.  It's brutal if it's something like a full on search interface with complex layout.

Comment: @Simon Dugré - What Pete M said. Remember that a library can contain resources which can be images, scripts or whatever you want. It can contain the designer elements used when placing the control on your canvas. It's just that you have to build much of it programmatically just as Pete M suggested.

Comment: @Thomas - Thank you. Do you have an idea if it's that way Telerik, Infragistics, and other one like that use it for their control? I mean, I just use them as a reference, I don't even think to do something similar to that lol

Comment: @Simon Dugré - Indeed that is how Telerik and Infragistics create their libraries. They are all made up of server controls with the resources baked into the library. In addition, I believe both vendors (I know Telerik does) also provide the raw resources (images, scripts etc) that go into those files.

Comment: I know a way that Infragistics use ressources (JS, CSS, images and others) ... it creates a complete other Application in ISS and stock ressources in there. On development, you have to copy good files. Anyway, thank you Thomas. I've just found an exemple and I'll check this out. Thanks again!